# Creating a fixed Canonical URL with dynamic periodical content

Tags: seo, canonical-url, next.js

I'm making a nextjs website that has multiple magazines with periodical issues using the following dynamic route structure:
`~/magazines/[magazine-title]/[issue-no]`

so the URL `~/magazines/social-innovation-magazine/1` would obviously go to a page that displays the 1st issue of "Social Innovation Magazine" and that page has a canonical that matches its URL.

Now, I wanna create a fixed route that would go to the latest issue of a specific magazine, something like:
`~/magazines/[magazine-title]/latest` -or- `~/magazines/[magazine-title]`

So the URL `~/magazines/social-innovation-magazine/latest` would take the visitor to the latest issue page of "Social Innovation Magazine" - let's say the latest issue is currently number 11 -  that way I would have to keep changing the canonical link in "latest" to match the URL of the latest issue number (11,12...)

Is that the right way to do it SEO wise? is it OK to keep changing the canonical? and if not, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the canonical often like that seems like something that Google algorithms might not like. I don't see this use case being mentioned on Googles help page: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls

Wouldn't it be better to simply redirect /latest to the last edition directly?

Comment: Well yes actually that's what I've eventually decided to do after doing some research... a 307 redirect.. I've always been hesitant when it comes to redirects because I didn't have a full understanding of how it all works. That being said, I'm still thinking about the option of a rewrite instead of a redirect since it's a next/react app.. but I'm not sure yet